# Excluding a particular file extension while reading from a folder

Tags: r

I have many files inside a folder with **xlm**, **xls** and **xlsx** and I want to read only file with type **xls**, **xlsx** .

```
xlsxfile.list <- list.files(path = path, pattern='*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
filePath  <- list.files(path=path,recursive=T,pattern=".xlsx",full.names=T)
```

If I use the above mentioned code, I am not able to read .xls file and if I change the pattern to **.xls** than I can see that **.xlm** files are also included into file list which i dont want.

Is there any library or simple way to achieve this. I am pretty new to R so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use something like `.*xls$ | .*xlsx$`(without the spacing)?

Comment: @NelsonGon i was not aware that we can use pipe like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.files(path = 'path', pattern='*.xls$|*.xlsx', full.names = TRUE)
```

In pattern, `$` denotes end of string and `|` is 'or'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern `*.xlsx?`, where it will match no matter if the extension has the last `x`

```
list.files(path = 'path', pattern='*.xlsx?', full.names = TRUE)
```